# Why are there no longer any biplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

Is there an aerodynamic reason why the concept of biplane or triplane has been completely abandoned? Practically all planes were biplanes in WW1, and in WW2 practically none were developed.

Comment: Whilst not strictly a duplicate the top answer to [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/what-special-handling-characteristics-or-techniques-do-biplanes-have) covers it pretty well.  Essentially in the early years of flight the advantages of biplanes outweighed the disadvantages; as material science and engine power improved this reversed and monoplanes became dominant.

Comment: Viking Dragonfly, Pitts Special, Rutan had at least one with canard large enough to count as a wing.

Comment: You'd think a bi-plane design would be really good for drones, and should be lighter in weight since you don't need as much structural support as really long wings need. And I'd think the drag problem could be overcome by how you choose to position the 2 wings. MIT and the Japanese have looked at a 1935 design that would use 2 wings to [cancel out a sonic boom for supersonic passenger planes](http://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/a7517/the-return-of-the-supersonic-biplane-7505124/).

Answer (score 37):

**Firstly, there are:**

[For example this company currently makes a biplane](http://www.wacoaircraft.com)

But the **main reason** is that they're inefficient, and don't really do much that a monoplane can't.

They produce a lot of drag compared to the amount of lift they produce, meaning they use a lot of fuel to travel the same distance. They have fairly poor visibility, which is usually considered a bad thing!

They do have a few advantages - they have a good roll rate, making them quite maneuverable, and they have a very low stall speed and can fly on little power, meaning they can fly slowly very well (where their increased drag doesn't make much difference: drag increases with the **square** of airspeed)

Overall, though, the above makes them suited only to aerobatics, which can also be performed by monoplanes. Advances in wing design and composite materials take away most of the advantages of a biplane for any other use: ie actually travelling (the main purpose of an aeroplane) and carrying a load.

Overall, then, they're more complex than a monoplane, less efficient, and aren't much more manoeuverable. They have more disadvantages than advantages.

**Biplanes were popular in WWI** not because of any inherent advantage, but simply because technology hadn't advanced far enough to allow any other options. Once the monoplane was properly developed, it allowed **much** higher speeds (450mph for a late WWII fighter, 300mph for an Early WWII fighter, compared to around 120 mph for a late WWI fighter). High speed fighters beat low speed fighters (at least before stealth technology and guided missiles)

There **were** a few leftover biplanes in WWII - The Fairey Swordfish torpedo bomber was one of the most widely used, as the low speed and good lift from the biplane design allowed it to carry a heavy torpedo, while the drag issues didn't matter at the slow speeds they needed to fly to be able to release the torpedo properly and on target. Others were the Gloster Gladiator (UK), Fiat CR.42 (Italy) and Polikarpov I-15 (Soviet Union) which achieved varying levels of success in the early stages, but were well and truly outclassed when facing even early-war monoplanes.

[This answer on a similar question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/what-special-handling-characteristics-or-techniques-do-biplanes-have?lq=1) gives some useful context about the direct advantages and disadvantages. It doesn't directly explain why biplanes fell out of favour, but it may help understand my own answer here.

Comment: 'they have a good roll rate', could you explain this? It seems to me that the roll rate is mainly dependent on the size and efficiency of the ailerons. Also, more mass far away from the center of gravity would mean a larger moment of inertia.

Comment: @ROIMaison - they (biplanes) have LESS mass far away from the centre of gravity because the wings are shorter (up to half the length of a comparable monoplane wing) and can also be lighter in some cases. It also affects how much wing is "resisting" the roll through the air, similar to how clipped wings work - see the Spitfire L.F (clipped wings for roll rate at low altitude) vs the Spitfire F (Regular) variants. Ailerons make some difference, but for a comparable aileron size and wing area, a biplane will roll better than a monoplane

Comment: Oh right, didn't thought about the shorter wings :) thanks for the explanation

Comment: @JonStory I will suggest to include in your answer that biplane wings produce more drag as longer wings (biggest aspect ratio) produce less drag. On top all the strings connecting both wings produce not needed drag.

Comment: Being able to fly at a slow speed seems very important when your civilization is struggling to create light, efficient engines. You know, like the early 20th century.

Comment: Don't forget the Antonov An-2 utility biplane, still flying! It is an old design (1947) but is still in production. It's even being constantly updated with new variants being developed as recently as 2013.

Comment: Another advantage of biplanes is that they are very good in a *bush plane* role, where the slow take-off and landing speeds and the short wings help operation in the wilderness where the terrain is rugged and full of obstacles. This is a niche role where biplanes are often used even today. The famous An-2 can land almost anywhere, as it has a stall speed so low it can basically land like a parachute, an impressive feat for an aircraft of that size.

Comment: If the purpose of an airplane was to fly around an area at moderate altitude for as long as possible on a given amount of fuel, without having to go anywhere (e.g. for purposes of extended reconnaissance, communications forwarding, etc.) would a monoplane be able to do the job with less energy per hour?  How would its energy requirements compare with those of a non-tethered blimp that need to be able to keep its general position in the presence of moderate winds?

Comment: @supercat That's an interesting question, you might wanna post it. I'm pretty sure, however, that the monoplane will be more efficient, **but only if** it has an engine for travelling at the same speed as the bi-plane. Otherwise, with the drag increasing as the square of the velocity, the extra drag probably overcomes the lesser form drag of the wing configuration. Don't know much about blimps, but if wind speeds are on the order of 20 or 30 kmh, compare that to a biplane cruising at 200 kmh and you can see that overcoming drag (or wind, relative) should be easier for the blimp.

Comment: @supercat: Don't forget crop dusters, which _also_ have to "fly around an area at moderate altitude for as long as possible on a given amount of fuel, without having to go anywhere".  Okay, not strictly as long as _possible_, but if you're spraying a lot of field...

Comment: @Sean: I'm not sure if new biplanes are still being manufactured for the purposes of crop dusting, but that was certainly one of the purposes I'd been thinking of, though I forgot to list it except as the "etc.".

Answer (score 5):

Well there ARE still biplanes produced today, either for nostalgic, or recreational reasons; they're just cool and harken back to classic age in aviation.  Biplanes are still popular with aerobatic pilots today for their agility as well.

The chief reasons the biplane largely went the way of the dinosaur have to do primarily with aerodynamics and structural mechanics.  When the cantilevered wing was perfected as well as construction from lightweight, high strength aluminum alloys which facilitated the monoplane, aircraft designers could take advantage of the superior characteristics of a monoplane, specifically much lower drag, allowing for higher speed flight.  World War II accelerated this transition, as the need for higher performance military fighters made the monoplane extremely attractive to designers on both sides.

But a Stearman or a Pitts are still a hell of a lot of fun to fly.