# Why aren't Biplanes designs used when size and wing span restrictions are involved?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-physics

This [research paper](https://scholarsmine.mst.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4425&context=masters_theses) shows that for a given aspect ratio and wing area, compared to a monoplane a biplane produced a better L/D. So, wouldn't it make more sense to manufacture biplanes for subsonic flight instead when size and wingspan restrictions are involved?

Comment: Without reading the 100+ pages, could you point to the section where it's claimed that biplanes produce better L/D than monoplanes? That claim runs contrary to what I've always understood. There's much more interface drag for a biplane, and the wings also interfere with each other. Both lead to more D for the same amount of L.

Comment: @KennSebesta, most of the paper just consists of appendices and the whole thing is just a wind tunnel test experiment, if you want the cliff notes for the lower L/D, check out the conclusion section.

Comment: [Would it be beneficial for the Boeing 777x to have a biplane wing design?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38157/3201) and [Why are there no longer any biplanes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12143/3201)

Comment: So, is the research paper wrong when it claims that biplanes have a lower L/D for a given wing area and aspect ratio?

Comment: I don't think anyone here is going to read a random paper to refute it. It's entirely possible that the linked masters thesis highlights a very specific point where biplanes could conceivably do better. I think if you want an answer here, you need to rephrase the question with the specific point in question so we can address it.

Comment: Biplane airplanes do have a better L/D but this is true only when the wingspan must be kept short due to some other limitations.

If you attach a second wing to a monoplane then each wing must generate only ½ of the total lift; being the induced drag proportional to L² then each wing generates now only ¼ of induced drag; the total induced drag is therefore ¼+¼=½ of the monoplane case. Amazing result. Anyway induced drag is also inversely proportional to wingspan squared: the same reduction of ½ can be obtained simply increasing wingspan of some 40%. What's better depends on other constraints

Comment: @sophit actually a good answer if they reopen. A bi-plane configuration would also enable higher altitudes, as was found out in [1938](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Pezzi_(aviator)).  Imagine a Concorde fuselage with 2 wings, perhaps looking a bit like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handley_Page_H.P.42).