# Do horizontal stabiliser force direction change with CG variation for a given aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-physics, stability, flight-dynamics, horizontal-stabilizer

I am wondering about the direction in which horizontal stabilizer provide force. I know that it can provide either upforce or downforce. But I am wondering whether is it determined for a particular airplane, I mean it is established for example that B737 tail will provide only a downforce and CG limits are set up in a way that when correctly loaded the tailplane will provide every single time a downforce or it depends from the CG location that tailplane will have to provide either a downforce or an upforce?

Comment: When I read the first sentence, I thought the rest of the question would be about horizontal component of the mentioned force.

Comment: You may find section 6.1.6 in "See How It Flies" to be instructive-- be sure and read the entire section to the end.  https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoastab.html#sec-pitch-equilibrium  .  See also section 6.1.1-- all the illustrations and explanations in section 6.1.1 are built around the idea of a LIFTING tail, further re-inforcing the idea that this is NOT incompatible with pitch stability -- https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoastab.html#sec-teeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal cruise condition, which minimises induced drag, is for the tail to exert zero lift. This avoids any wasteful tip vortices from the tail.

However for most planes the CG shifts during flight, if only because fuel is being used up. Also, trim conditions change with speed, rate of climb, altitude and a host of other variables during flight. The tail spends most of its time a little away from the ideal zero-lift condition, and it can go either way.

The "lifting tail" was much discussed in the early years of aviation. It has a destabilising effect which limits the stable CG range and every plane has a maximum safe level of lift from the tail while remaining stable. Nevertheless, away from that limit it contributes lift which helps to offload the wing and allows it to be that bit smaller. 
According to Berriman; *Aviation*, Methuen, 1913.

> "On some machines the tail planes are cambered like the wings and help to support the weight in flight. The angle of incidence of the tail is less than that of the wings, however, and the principle [of weathercock stability] apples equally to such cases." -- Page 69.

Berriman gives some supporting analysis in terms of CG and CP to explain what he summarises as weathercock stability. The subtleties of the lifting tail would be further elaborated in subsequent years.

The bigger the tail, the greater the CG range can be accommodated, and also the greater the temptation to offload the wing a little. The limit is the tandem-wing aircraft, where for stability the fore wing is loaded more heavily than the aft, but the aft still contributes substantially to the lift under all flight conditions. A tandem-wing modification of the Westland Lysander flew experimentally during WWII and test pilot Harald Penrose confirmed that its handling was more stable than the conventional version and had a greater CG range.

So ultimately, every plane has its own practical tail loading, which may be normally up, normally down, or variable around the zero point.

There is a myth that for a plane to be stable the tail must always exert a downforce. This seems to arise among students for two reasons. One is that, when the AoA increases, dynamically it must exert a larger *relative change* in downward moment about the aerodynamic center than the wing's upward moment. Diagrams showing this effect always have a large down-arrow at the tail and it is easy for the student to forget that this is a relative change not an absolute value. The other is that the wing works hardest at takeoff, when fully laden and at its slowest flying speed; when the tail pushes sharply down to rotate the nose up, the wing has to compensate for that as well, so this is the design condition for sizing the wing and everybody has to learn it. Put that first diagram alongside and you have a myth in the making. If you failed to understand any of this paragraph, then you too may fall for it!

Comment: *There is a myth that for a plane to be stable the tail must always exert a downforce* – finally, I'm not alone with that opinion here!

Comment: @PeterKämpf Don't worry, I'll continue sharing a link to the section about [pitchwise equilibrium](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoastab.html#sec-pitch-equilibrium) of "how it flies" in [comments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77182/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-a-tail-providing-lift-tandem-wings-included#comment201967_77182) when needed.

Comment: @ManuH you have to do better than that av8n article written by who knows who.  Link me to a NASA or Boeing article or a university paper that describes what you guys are talking about.  I have had no luck.

Comment: So many folks miss the difference in horizontal stabilizer decalage and trim.  Guy correctly pointed out the tail force at optimal wing AOA (in cruise) is most efficient at **zero, niether up or down**.  It is the elevator/trim tab that accomodates the CG range.  One point I would question is (the horizontal stabilizer) "dynamicly, it must exert a larger downward moment" .  Actually, it is less, and, at higher AOA, it is supposed to **help the wing push the nose down**.  "Down force" tails do have a lower risk of stalling after the wing does, but poorly designed ones are not exempt.

Comment: Again.  Show. Me. An. Authoritative. Source..., like a NASA, Boeing, or university article that describes what you are saying, and I will eat my virtual shorts. Should be easy!  Should be everywhere no?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni You misquote me: I wrote ""dynamically, it must exert a larger **relative change** in downward moment" That change is of course the negative one you mention. The distinctions between absolute values, relative differences and rates of change need to be clearly borne in mind at all times!

Comment: @JohnK I gave an authoritative source in a comment on your answer. My recommendation is that you check out any basic degree-course-oriented text book on aerodynamics. If nothing else, it will tell you what to look for on the NASA web site.

Comment: Well, I posted part of an article from a Boeing website on my post.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Boeing are certainly wrong. The guy who wrote that never put their name to it. No peer review, no academic credentials, nada. It's sadly typical of the half-baked guff people often dish out to pilots who only need to fly it, not to understand its design. Never rely on company web sites! (and remember what Boeing never told the MAX pilots)

Comment: @JohnK The explanation of av8n is a single explanation working for all wings configuration (bi-wings like the prometeus, canard, classical downforce tail). [One single explanation for many configurations is preferable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) to an ad-hoc explanation for each configuration. And authoritative sources such as the Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge [can be incorrect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/548030/85763)

Comment: What about the Boeing article I linked?  Is that wrong?  The problem is av8n tries to lump dual lifting surfaces configs with conventional tail downforce configs when they are opposites.

Comment: Ahhhh... so av8n  right, Boeing wrong..  Cuz you say so.  Check.

Comment: @JohnK I also suggest you read chapter 3 of [Caughey, David A. "Introduction to aircraft stability and control course notes for M&AE 5070." Sibley School of Mechanical & Aerospace Engineering Cornell University (2011).](http://courses.cit.cornell.edu/mae5070/Caughey_2011_04.pdf)

Comment: @PeterKämpf -- re "There is a myth that for a plane to be stable the tail must always exert a downforce – finally, I'm not alone with that opinion here!" -- you've never been alone; during the few years that I've participated on ASE I've made multiple posts and offered multiple links in support of this--

Answer (score -2):

In stabilized steady state flight, if the tail is providing lift UP, it means it is opposing a net pitch up moment (it's lifting to keep the nose from rising).  To have a net pitch up moment, the CG must be aft of the "mean center of lift" or Neutral Point, in order to create a nose up torque resultant from mass acting about NP.  This is a dynamically unstable condition and only FBW fighters can operate this way.

In any normal airplane, the CG must always be forward of the Neutral Point, this distance being called "positive static margin".  A positive static margin means there is always a net nose down pitching moment present and the tail has to provide down force to balance it out.  The only time the tail will lift up is during maneuvering cases where a stick forward control input is sufficient to pitch the airplane over faster than the natural pitching moment can do it.  Then the tail will be lifting, briefly.

If the tail was lifting in any normal steady state case, it would mean that that Static Margin is negative, and that to slow down, the trimable tail's incidence would have to move ***leading edge up*** and the elevator move down.  I am not aware of any aircraft in existence in this universe with a conventional tail where the elevator has to move down, or the stab has to move LE up, to slow down.

From [Boeing](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_02/textonly/fo01txt.html):

> 1 Positive and Relaxed Longitudinal Static Stability
>   In flight, the wings of a conventional airplane generate a nose down pitching moment. To balance this, a download is required on the tail. Airplanes loaded with an aft forward CG require less download on the tail.

Since download on the tail is negative lift, effectively increasing the weight of the airplane, the location of the CG affects the cruise performance of any airplane. Flying at an aft CG will reduce the download on the tail and improve cruise performance.

When airplanes are operated near the aft CG limit, download on the tail is minimized and angles of attack and drag are reduced. However, moving the CG aft reduces the longitudinal static stability of the airplane, something that all flight crews should be aware of (see figure 1 and "Static Longitudinal Stability and Speed Stability" below).

As airspeed varies from a trimmed condition, the column force required to maintain a new speed (without re-trimming) is a measure of static longitudinal stability. For any conventional airplane, the location of the CG has the strongest influence on static longitudinal stability. For a statically stable airplane the required column force, as speed varies from the trimmed condition, is less at an aft CG than it is at a forward CG. The minimum average gradient allowed by U.S. Federal Aviation Administration FAR Part 25 is one pound for each six knots. As the CG moves aft, it reaches a point where the stick force per knot drops to zero, then reverses. This location is called the neutral point. The difference between the actual CG location and the neutral point is called the static margin. With a CG forward of the neutral point, an airplane has a positive static margin and positive static longitudinal stability. At a CG aft of the neutral point, an airplane has a negative static margin, is statically unstable, and requires some form of augmentation to be flown with an acceptable workload.<

Comment: That old chestnut. It is true that the tail must provide a dynamic *relative* downforce when the AoA changes, but it can perfectly well be trimmed for a small net up-force in normal flight.

Comment: Sorry not buying it.  You are saying airplanes will fly with negative static margin.  Again, find me an AUTHORITATIVE source for this, NOT some other posting on here.  I have found nothing that says airplanes will fly with negative static margin, neither on line or in the books I have.  They all refer to a requirement for positive static margin, and to have positive static margin there has to be a ND pitching moment for the tail to oppose.  If the tail is lifting there is negative static margin.  If the tail was lifting, and speed decreased suddenly, the nose would pitch up.

Comment: Nope. Static margin and absolute tail downforce are not directly related, that is the cheap fallacy you have fallen for. Static margin is related to the change in up/downforce moment with AoA. If you cannot understand that, then you will not understand why you have been misled.

Comment: Fine. Refer me to an article outside of this forum, from say, NASA, that describes it.  Surely it's described as you say all over the place, right?  Should be easy.

Comment: JohnK Do your own Internet search. Easier for me to take the first standard textbook on my shelf. LJ Clancy; *Aerodynamics*, 1975, UK Pitman edn p.518. "*the static margin is now defined directly as -(dCm/dCl)*" where Cm is the pitching moment coefficient and CL is the lift coefficient. So its' all to do with the rates of change of coefficients, nothing to do with absolute tail load.

Comment: The rates of change of coefficients has to do with the tail's steeper lift slope, which is why they use thin airfoils.  The downforce of the tail declines more steeply then the lift of the main wing, allowing the nose to drop.  If the tail is lifting, the steeper decline in lift will make the nose pitch UP.  I wouldn't want to be in such an airplane.

Comment: @John K I submit a "tail lifter" can be stable within its **design CG range**.  Indeed, the XB-70 would be an extreme example of this.  A down lifting tail (with more pitch down authority) is good insurance with a swept wing design (because the wing tips go first in a stall). Uplifting tails are reputed to be more dangerous because most of their throw/trim is already used up.  But is one **designs** CG further back, an uplifting tail could be made to work.  Since they are less efficient, they are rare (essentially bi-planes).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni no you are describing tandem wings which is a different thing entirely.  A tandem wing, as with a canard, must have the forward wing with a steeper lift slope than the aft one. Coming up with an airfoil like that, which will give good flight characteristics, for a forward wing that is making the majority of the total lift is tough.  Rutan struggled with this until they came up with the U of Glasgow forward wing airfoil for the Vari Eze and follow-on designs which produces high lift plus desirable pitch and stall characteristics.

Comment: @JohnK. "If the tail is lifting, the steeper decline in lift..." has it totally back to front. If the tail is lifting, increase in AoA will increase its lift not reduce it. Really, with such basic howlers as this in your arguments, there is little point in my commenting further.

Comment: @GuyInchbald  remember the courtesy rules here.  Anyway, you are describing the tail's reaction to gusts changing AOA and applying a restorative tendency.  I'm talking about static stability and the ability of an airplane to maintain trim speed and positive stick forces.  If the tail is lifting in a steady state condition, the CG is aft of the NP, an unstable case, and stick forces reverse.  So the Boeing article I linked is wrong?

Comment: @JohnK I'm afraid Guy is right on this one

Comment: @JZYL ok so let's be clear.  You are saying that you can have the CG forward of the NP, the normal static margin, and with such arrangement, have a nose UP pitching moment, requiring the tail to lift UP to trim at the same time?

Comment: No, static margin is not related to tail lift direction. Your confusion stems from your belief that an aircraft pitches about the NP. That's not accurate: it pitches about the CG, always. NP is a stability point, not the point of rotation.

Comment: But in the static trimmed flight case, we aren't talking about rotations about an axis, we're are talking about static moments in balance about the net center of lift, the NP.  With the CG forward of the net center of lift, there is a ND pitching moment present, being the torque of the CG applying a gravitational force forward of the NP.  How can the tail be lifting up to maintain trim unless there is a NU pitching moment present, which would require CG aft of the NP? I have yet to see anybody here explain this.

Comment: In a static case, of course you can take the moments about NP. But NP isn't the CP of the wing-fuselage; so there's no reason to think that the moment from the wing-fuselage is zero. For the right CG and AOA, it can be positive at NP. In that case, the tail needs to provide up-lift to achieve static moment balance.

Comment: NP is the sum total of lifting moments so is the "net" center of lift taking into account wing, fuselage, nacelles, etc. (the whole problem with the MAX stemmed from the engines moving the NP forward).  In any case, if the tail is lifting, that means its AOA is below the zero lift line of the tail in order to produce up lift, which means the moment induced by air loads on the elevator surface is trailing edge UP (like an aileron), which is called control reversal, requiring forward stick pressure to maintain pitch, and to trim, the tab would have to work in the opposite direction.